# dovecot draft messages missing message-id

Tags: python, imap

when I append a message to the drafts folder, the message does not have a message-id.  I am using python 2.5 This is messing my program up as there is no solid way to get the email.  I am working around that right now, but when I try to expunge it, the email does not get deleted.  Also, when I select on the folder, it returns "ok", 0.  If I select a folder with a normal email, I get "ok", 1.

Is there a reason that the email does not have a message-id?
Is there a way to append the email in a way that it will have a message-id?

Any idea's why it won't expunge?

Comment: Write a message-id yourself. One will be added by the submission server when you send the mail, if you want it earlier you can make it as early as you want. I like to use <securehashofmessagecontent@myappsdoma.in>, but e.g. <entropy@anyotherdoma.in> works too, so long as collisions with other messages are unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did.